# Angular Async pipe does not properly update in Unit Tests

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, jasmine

I'm facing an issue with rendering updating Observables through `async` pipe in HTML while writing unit tests.

The idea is that I want test not just the component but whether child components are both rendered and have correct Inputs.

This is the minimal example that the issue occurs:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let plan of plans$ | async">
  <child-component [plan]="plan"></child-component>
</ng-container>

Visible plans: {{ plans$ | async | json }}
```

The minimal example of Component:

```
export class RecommendationsComponent implements OnInit {
  public plans$: Observable<Plan[]>;

  constructor(private readonly _store: Store<State>) {
    this.plans$ = this._store.pipe(select(selectRecommendationsPayload));
  }

  public ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getRecommendations(); // Action dispatch, state is filled with data
  }
}
```

Unit test for this module/component:

```
describe('Recommendations', () => {
  let component: RecommendationsComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<RecommendationsComponent>;
  let store: Store<any>;
  let mockStore: MockStore<any>;
  let actions$: ReplaySubject<any> = new ReplaySubject<any>();

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [RecommendationsComponent],
      imports: [RouterTestingModule.withRoutes([]), HttpClientTestingModule],
      providers: [
        MockStore,
        provideMockStore({ initialState: initialStateMock }),
        provideMockActions(() => actions$),
      ],
    });

    store = TestBed.inject(Store);
    mockStore = TestBed.inject(MockStore);

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(RecommendationsComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should successfully retrieve and handle plans', () => {
    recommendationsService.getRecommendations = jasmine.createSpy().and.returnValue(of(plans)); // Mock BE response with non-empty data

    component.plans$.subscribe(plans => {
      console.log(plans);
      console.log(fixture.debugElement);
      // A few expect() based on state and HTML...
      // This fires since all logic starts on ngOnInit() lifecycle
    });
  });
});
```

While real code and `console.log(plans);` in unit test show correct data, for some reason the `plans$ | async` in HTML always has default state. The issue is solely related to HTML.

My attempted tries:

1. Add `fixture.detectChanges();` - Added this line to almost every second line (to such extreme) in both `beforeEach()` and in `it` test case but nothing was changed
2. Hardcoded with `component.plans$ = of([ { name: 'name' } as any ]);` in `it` test case (I was wondering if this had something to do with Store/MockStore but even hardcoded value appears to be not working in HTML)
3. Use `fixture.whenRenderingDone().then(async () => { <code> });` in entire test case (perhaps HTML was not rendered by the time `console.log()` lines came up)
4. Similar to the third, I also tried with `setTimeout()`, with same reasoning

My other thoughts are also:

1. I have missed something in `declarations`, `imports`, etc.?
2. MockStore/Store does not properly trigger changes to `async` pipes (although they work for `subscribe()`)

If something is missing, let me know. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

What is strange to me is that you have a handle on both `store` and `mockStore`.

I think you should only use one. I don't have much experience with mockStore so I will try the actual store. Try doing `integration testing` as shown [here](https://ngrx.io/guide/store/testing). With integration testing we have the actual store and not a mock store.

```
describe('Recommendations', () => {
  let component: RecommendationsComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<RecommendationsComponent>;
  let store: Store<any>;
  let actions$: ReplaySubject<any> = new ReplaySubject<any>();

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [RecommendationsComponent],
      imports: [
         RouterTestingModule.withRoutes([]), 
         HttpClientTestingModule,
         StoreModule.forRoot({
           // Pay attention here, make sure this is provided in a way
           // where your selectors will work (make sure the structure is
           // good)
           recommendations: recommendationsReducer,
         })
      ],
    });

    store = TestBed.inject(Store);
    // load the recommendations into the store by dispatching
    store.dispatch(new loadRecommendations([]));
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(RecommendationsComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    // see your state here, make sure the selector works
    store.subscribe(state => console.log(state));
    // any time you want to change plans, do another dispatch
    store.dispatch(new loadRecommendations([/* add stuff here */]));
    // the following above should make plans$ emit every time
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });
  

 // !! -- The rest is up to you from now on but what I presented above
 // should help in getting new plans$ with the async pipe !!-

  it('should successfully retrieve and handle plans', () => {
    recommendationsService.getRecommendations = jasmine.createSpy().and.returnValue(of(plans)); // Mock BE response with non-empty data

    component.plans$.subscribe(plans => {
      console.log(plans);
      console.log(fixture.debugElement);
      // A few expect() based on state and HTML...
      // This fires since all logic starts on ngOnInit() lifecycle
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Hmm, doesn't appear to be working for me (`Error: Invalid provider for the NgModule 'DynamicTestModule' - only instances of Provider and Type are allowed`). I'm using 2 different Stores as there are cases where either Effects or actions are not triggered. I might be heading the wrong way. Thank you for the code and link, I will try to update and test to see whether I can fix.

Comment: You shouldn't provide effects, just the reducer in StoreModue.forRoot.